# Как можно получить IndexOutOfBoundException, если index меньше size?

Tags: java, исключения

Разве это возможно? Объясните пожалуйста, когда такое возможно и почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Даже не знаю, как показать какой-либо кусок кода. Во-первых, ситуация очень странная. Во-вторых, к ней меня привела длинная цепочка вызовов (классы сильно взаимосвязаны). Даже не могу предположить где может быть проблема. Скажу только, что я получаю исключение запуская сложную задачу в SwingWorker.

**UPD:** Благодаря полученным ответам, я понял на какой метод следует обратить наиболее пристальное внимание:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        solver = new MultidimensionalSolver(manager.getTask());
        manager.getTask().setSolution(solver.getSolution().getSolution());
        while (!solver.isSolutionFind() && flag) {
            solver.findSolution();
            manager.getTask().setSolution(
                    solver.getSolution().getSolution());
            publish();
            iter++;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Здесь класс MultidimensionalSolver работает с теми же данными, которые выводятся на экран в методе process(), вызываемом при вызове publish(). Получается поток в методе publish настолько обгоняет поток в методе doInBackground?

Comment: Создайте для апдейта отдельный вопрос, и поясните в нем подробно, что и где у вас происходит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Такое может запросто случиться, если доступ к вашему `ArrayList` идет из нескольких потоков, при этом отсутствует синхронизация. Судя по тому, что вы используете `SwingWorker`, именно это и происходит. Сценарий может быть такой:

1. Первый поток пытается взять элемент с индексом 2. При этом в
   коллекции, допустим, всего 1 элемент.
2. В методе `rangeCheck` код этого потока заходит внутрь условия:

   ```
   private void rangeCheck(int index) {
       if (index >= size)
           throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
   }
   ```
3. Второй поток добавляет 2 элемента (теперь их становится 3).
4. Первый поток выбрасывает исключение со странным сообщением,
   поскольку метод `outOfBoundsMsg` подхватил новое значение `size`.

Решение: синхронизировать доступ (и чтение, и запись) к коллекции с помощью локов, либо использовать потокобезопасный вариант коллекции.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Разрешите немного уточнить? Простите мою неграмотность, локи - это вы synchonized имеете в виду? А потокобезопасный вариант коллекции - это классы из пакета java.util.concurrent?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров оба ответа "да". Если вы очень редко пишете и очень часто читаете, можете использовать `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. В противном случае вызов `Collections.synchronizedList` и `synchonized` на нем будет проще и дешевле.

Comment: а может быть еще такой вариант решения: мне в моей программе нужно все-таки что бы потоки именно вместе обращались к коллекции: один поток решает задачу, а другой обновляет данные в GUI. В потоке, который рисует GUI, я слишком рано вызываю метод, который обращается к данным коллекции(теперь я это понял, спасибо вам! :)) Если этот метод просто вызывать позже, когда поток, отвечающий за решения уже добавил в коллекцию все необходимые элементы (логике задачи это не будет противоречить), тогда можно потоки оставить асинхронными? Или асинхронность в данном случае неприемлима?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров если этап решения однократный, а этап отображения должен идти строго после этапа решения, то да, вы можете сначала сделать расчет, а потом вывести это в UI. Но только оставить эти этапы в отдельных потоках с несинхронизированным обращением к общим данным все равно чревато ошибками в будущем. Можете убрать shared данные и сделать так, чтобы этап решения возвращал готовый массив, который будет использоваться на этапе отображения.